# Understanding a proof from Serge Lang's "Linear Algebra" p. 15

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working through Serge Lang's undergraduate text: "Linear Algebra" and I've gotten hung up on a particular claim in one of his proofs on p. 15.

The result is:

**Theorem 3.1:** Let $V$ be a vector space over the field
$K$. Let $\left\{ v_{1},\ldots,v_{m}\right\} $ be a basis of $V$
over $K$. Let $w_{1},\ldots,w_{n}$ be elements of $V$, and assume
that $n>m$. Then $w_{1},\ldots,w_{n}$ are linearly dependent.

His proof starts out in the following way.

*Proof:* Assume that $w_{1},\ldots,w_{n}$ are linearly independent. Since $\left\{ v_{1},\ldots,v_{m}\right\} $ is a basis, there exists elements $a_{1},\ldots,a_{m}\in K$ such that $w_{1}=a_{1}v_{1}+\cdots+a_{m}v_{m} $.

And here is the part that I am having trouble with:

By assumption, we know that $w_{1}\neq O$ and hence some $a_{i}\ne0$.

I do not understand how he deduces that $w_{1}\neq O$. He has assumed that $w_{1},\ldots,w_{n}$ are linearly independent, which means that if we have a a linear combination of the form $a_{1}w_{1}+\cdots+a_{n}w_{n}=O$ then all of the coefficients $a_{1},\ldots,a_{m}$ must be zero. But I do not understand how to deduce from this that a particular $w_{i}\neq O$.

It seems like there should be a simple explanation, but I have not been able to puzzle it out.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Yes, of course. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: **Hint:** any set with the zero vector is linearly dependent. Since he is supposing L.I. then...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

If $w_1=0$ then what we can deduce from this equality

$$w_1+0w_2+\cdots+0w_n=0 ?$$